# Mediaplayer plays music after 1 or 1.5 sec delays in Nexus Android 4.4.3

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, nexus-5

I am using mediaplayer class to play .aac music files which is under raw resource. All the device performs well and start playing of each .aac file on user interaction  but Nexus 5 with having Android 4.4.3 creating problem , It plays music after 1 or 2 sec delay.
Also a same code working fine with Android Kitkat 4.4.2 (MOTO G Android Device)
Below is my code

```
Intent i = new Intent(MusicClass.this, PlayerService.class);
        i.putExtra("isplaying", "stop");
        startService(i);
```

PlayerService class

```
public class PlayerService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener
private IMyRemoteService.Stub myRemoteServiceStub = new IMyRemoteService.Stub() {

    @Override
    public boolean isMusicPlaying() throws RemoteException {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have referred below links but not luck [Link 1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Multimedia) & [Link 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer)
So waht can be the solution  for Android